# open link on new window with top bar from my site

Tags: php, ajax

How my brothers cleared of any possible link to my site once pressed opens the page again and be the top bar of my site such as the following

http://www.example.com/index.html

[Edit]
How to render a bar at the top of a website that shows content from some other site in its body.

i have this ode to get rss from other site

```
gfeedfetcher.prototype._displayresult=function(feeds){
    var rssoutput=(this.itemcontainer=="<li>")? "<ul>\n" : ""
    gfeedfetcher._sortarray(feeds, this.sortstring)
    for (var i=0; i<feeds.length; i++){
        var itemtitle="<a href=\"" + feeds[i].link + "\" target=\"" + this.linktarget + "\" class=\"titlefield\">" + feeds[i].title + "</a>"
        var itemlabel=/label/i.test(this.showoptions)? '<span class="labelfield">['+this.feeds[i].ddlabel+']</span>' : " "
        var itemdate=gfeedfetcher._formatdate(feeds[i].publishedDate, this.showoptions)
        var itemdescription=/description/i.test(this.showoptions)? "<br />"+feeds[i].content : /snippet/i.test(this.showoptions)? "<br />"+feeds[i].contentSnippet  : ""
        rssoutput+=this.itemcontainer + itemtitle + " " + itemlabel + " " + itemdate + "\n" + itemdescription + this.itemcontainer.replace("<", "</") + "\n\n"
    }
    rssoutput+=(this.itemcontainer=="<li>")? "</ul>" : ""
    this.feedcontainer.innerHTML=rssoutput
}
```

i need when click link open in other windows with i frame

Answer (score 0):

The site is just the top header with an

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

within

Check out more info at w3schools
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

Comment: i have this code to get rss from other site and i need when click title , open line on other windows on iframe

Comment: you want something that is clicked on outside the iframe to do something inside the iframe?

Comment: Well ill be dammed I did assume affiliation with W3C. I am very sorry. Is there a open source reference for everything lol....I find myself using asp.net and msdn for C#, and asp, and jquery.com for well jquery.